# Getting error is fresh google cloud wordpress install

Tags: wordpress

I installed WordPress on the google cloud, installed fine.

Can login to it via http://146.148.119.58/wp-login.php...

The problem is when I try to install a theme or a plugin that exceeds 2MB it gives the error:
The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.

I SSH to the MC and searched for php.ini... found it in two places, edited both... both php.ini didnt have an entry for it before.

I added to the php.ini:
; File Uploads
upload_max_filesize = 32M
post_max_filesize = 32M

I rebooted the server twice and still I get the same error, whenever trying to upload anything larger than 2MB.

Can someone please help? I am on the bronze support package, which means I dont get to speak to someone... really need  to overcome this issue.

Another reason is that I want to install Virtual Composer plugin, to have additional functionality when working with my WordPress pages.

Its really furstrating, such a small thing and it is stopping what needs to be done. Any assistance will be appreciated.

Thanks
josh folgado

PS. My email is me@joshfolgado.com

Answer (score 0):

add this to your .htaccess

`<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value post_max_size           32M
php_value upload_max_filesize     64M
php_value memory_limit            512M
</IfModule>`

Comment: Thanks a lot for coming back to me.

Comment: I did a find on the wordpress server and there are 4 locations. 

Locations:
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup/lib/
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup/frames/lib/
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/
/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/askimet/

Which one is the right location to edit .htaccess?

Thanks again
Josh Folgado

Comment: I added a .htaccess file with the content above to /wordpress and afterwards I couldnt access it anymore via the browser, still had access through SSH and working on command line. Only after deleting the fie that that I could login again. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Btw resolved issue... what I did was to install a plugin (WP Htaccess Editor), created a new .htaccess file and added:

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value post_max_size           32M
php_value upload_max_filesize     64M
php_value memory_limit            512M
</IfModule>

After that I could upload larger templates and other code.

Thanks a lot for getting me in the right direction.

Take care
Josh

Comment: Happy that i helped you, it would be great if you will accept the solution then to get some rewards, just click on the up arrow.

Comment: Tried to click up arrow, system shows message that I need 15 reputation to do it.

Comment: Pity it doesnt allow new users such as myself to give a reward for someone that helped... it just doesnt look very fair. Sorry but could not vote. Take care and again thanks

Comment: no problem bro, i understand them also because I could create 100 accounts and vote for myself if the reputation is not needed. but thanks anyway bro :)